# AndroidStudio(gradle)でビルドエラー Process finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio

AndroidStudioでビルドエラーが出て困っています。
Windows7
java version "1.8.0_40"
AndroidStudio 1.1.0

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    >com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
    Process 'command 'C:\java\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

プロジェクトを作成しただけで特にコードは書いていないのですが、jarの参照を追加したところでエラーとなりました。

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
            defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.isopon.testrpc"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile files('libs/javassist.jar')
        compile files('libs/netty-3.2.1.Final.jar')
        compile files('libs/msgpack-0.6.6.jar')
        compile files('libs/msgpack-rpc-0.7.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar')
        compile files('libs/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar')
    }
```

原因がわからず困っています。
お知恵を拝借願えますか?

Comment: `compile files('libs/*.jar')` の行を全て削除してから再実行してみてください

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
再実行してみましたが目的のライブラリがimportできない状態になり、どうするべきか困り果てています。

Comment: となるとbuild.gradle全体の記述がどうなってるのか分からないと原因特定出来ないと思います。

Answer (score 3):

libs配下のjarファイル群は、
`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
の記述で全てincludeできています。

ですので`compile files('libs/○○.jar')`の記述は全て不要となります。

Comment: なるほど、わかりました。
ご回答頂きありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

私の環境でも同じ事象が発生しまして、その時に対処した方法を記載します。

Android Studioからのビルドでは詳細エラーがわかりませんので、コマンドラインで直接gradleを実行しました。

```
bash <ANDROID_STUDIO_HOME>/gradle/gradle-<version>/bin/gradle :app:dexDebug
```

(Windowsの場合は同ディレクトリ内にあるgradle.batを実行することになると思います。)

このコマンドも同様に失敗するのですが、Android Studio上のエラー表示に加えて、例外も出力されます。
この例外メッセージで原因を特定することができました。

私の場合、異なるライブラリjar内に、それぞれ同じ名称のクラスが含まれていたことが原因でした。

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define L;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```