# AndroidStudio(gradle)でビルドエラー (重複クラスでエラー?)

Tags: android, java, macos, android-studio, gradle

質問です。

AndroidStudio ビルドエラーで実行出来きなくて本当に困っています。
１ヶ月程前は実行出来ていた環境でした。
環境
OSX 10.10.4
AndroidStudio 1.2.2
jdk1.7.0_79.jdk

ソースと参考にしたURLを下に載せました。

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '0.12.412'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jp.trustridge.macaroni.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.6"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:+"

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:+'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // volley
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:+'

    // realm
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:+'

    // adjust
    //compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:+'
}
```

エラー文

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
    Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
    finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

参考URL　http://markfour.blogspot.jp/2015/03/androidsdkerrorexecution-failed-for.html
参考にしたスタックオーバーフローの質問
『[AndroidStudio(gradle)でビルドエラー Process finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/8020/7290)』

試した事

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`をコメントアウト→エラー(`Warning:(5, 31) 'ActionBarActivity' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`など)

```
//以下をコメントアウトでエラー
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:+"
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:+'
// volley
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:+'
// realm
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:+'

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
Error:(4, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
Error:(7, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
    '/Users/makki/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' 
    finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

追記8/10
・参考にしたサイトその３
http://markfour.blogspot.jp/2015/03/androidsdkerrorexecution-failed-for.html
重複エラーの修正の仕方が書いてありますが、自分場合どのようにすれば良いかわかりません。

追記8/10 (2)

[参照先](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8020/androidstudiogradle%E3%81%A7%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC-process-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2/12096#12096)のコマンドラインで直接gradleを実行方法がわかりません。
参考サイトを教えていただけると助かります。[こちらで質問しています。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14236/gradle%E3%82%92%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

追記8/11 
ターミナルからの実行結果

※helpタスクのログ削除
ーーーーーーーーーーーーー

追記 8/11(2)
gradlew buildを実行してみました。

```
makki-no-MacBook-Pro:gnoccho makki$ ./gradlew build
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 21.375 secs
makki-no-MacBook-Pro:gnoccho makki$
```

Comment: 「試した事」の前後でエラーが変わっているようです(exit valueが2->1)が、元々の状態でコマンドラインからgradleを実行するとどのような例外が出力されるでしょうか。[参照先](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/12096/2808)にも書きましたが、Android Studioからではビルドエラーの詳細がわからないので、まずはコマンドラインでgradleを実行しエラー原因を特定してみてください(そこで出力されたスタックトレースを追記していただけると回答可能になるかと思います)。必ずしも @makki さんの遭遇しているエラーと他の方のエラーとが同原因であるとは限りません。

Comment: 貼り付けられたログでは実行すべきタスクが指定されておらず、デフォルトタスクとして定義された help タスクが走っているようです。`$gradlew tasks` で実行可能なタスクの一覧を確認してみてください。プロジェクトのビルドをしたいのならおそらくは `$gradlew build` になるのではないかと思います。

Comment: help タスクのログは無用ですので削ってください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

貼り付けられたスタックトレースに出ていたエラーメッセージで検索してみたところ、次のものが見つかりました。

[android - Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

エラーの理由としてはプロジェクトに含まれるメソッド数が65535を超えてしまったためのようです。

なお上記QAに Google 公式の解説へのリンクがありました。

[Building Apps with Over 65K Methods | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

上記ページの Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle の節に解決策が書かれているようです。要点は次の２点。

> - Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex
> - Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class

build.grade の `defaultConfig` に

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

を加え、さらに `dependencies` に

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

を加えてみてください。
さらに manifest にも `MultiDexApplication` を参照するための記述を加える必要があるようです。具体的な記述は、上記の Google 解説ページを見てください。

#### 追記

上記の方法でビルドエラーを回避したとしても、この方法でできたバイナリは Android 4.0 未満では動作しないとのことです。ご注意を。

> **Limitations of the multidex support library**
>   Applications that use multidex may not start on devices that run versions of the platform earlier than Android 4.0 (API level 14) due to a Dalvik linearAlloc bug (Issue 22586).

Answer (score 5):

Google Play開発者サービス(Google Play services)は非常に大規模であるため、ライブラリをまるごと依存関係に追加してしまうと、今回エラーとして出ている[65K Methods Limit](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)に引っかかりやすくなります。

質問文中の

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

が該当しますが、これを削除し、自分のアプリケーションが必要とするライブラリのみ依存関係に追加することで、おそらくエラーを除去できると思います。
Google Play servicesがどのようなライブラリに分割されているかは下記公式サイトを参照してください。

- [Setting Up Google Play Services   |        Google APIs for Android   |        Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

たとえば、Google DriveのAPIを使用したいのであれば

```
compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0
```

となります。

一般的な対策としては [@holywise さんが記載されている方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/14262/2808)になるのですが、その対処を行う前に、まずは不要なライブラリ/メソッドを付随させないようにすべきかと考えます。
ファイルサイズの肥大化抑制にもつながります。

参考:

- [Google Play services and DEX method limits | Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html)
- [android - How to avoid 65k method limit while using Google Play Services - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589560/)
- [Android - 65K問題が起きた時の犯人を調べる方法 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/mattak@github/items/f27db9a7862ab9c84c6c)