# gradleをターミナルで実行したい

Tags: android, java, macos, android-studio, gradle

[AndroidStudioのビルドエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/13181/androidstudiogradle%E3%81%A7%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC-%E9%87%8D%E8%A4%87%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC)原因を特定するためにgradleをターミナルで実行したいです。
やり方を教えて下さい。

[参考にした質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8020/androidstudiogradle%E3%81%A7%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC-process-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2/12096#12096)
[参考にした質問その２](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11626/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2/12097#12097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidStudio には詳しくありませんが、作成したプロジェクトの中に `gradlew` というスクリプトがあるはずなので、ターミナルにてプロジェクトのディレクトリに移動して `gradlew` を実行すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

実行時にどのような引数を渡せばいいのかは build.gradle の記載に依存します。
細かい情報を表示させたければ引数のオプション `-i` でログレベルを info あたりにしてみると良いかもしれません。
必要に応じて `-s` スタックトレースオプションも付けてみてください。

#### 参考：

- [第6回　Android StudioとGradle［後編］：Android Studio最速入門～効率的にコーディングするための使い方｜gihyo.jp … 技術評論社](http://gihyo.jp/dev/serial/01/android_studio/0006)
- [第11章 Gradleのコマンドラインを使う](http://gradle.monochromeroad.com/docs/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html)
- [第18章 ロギング](http://gradle.monochromeroad.com/docs/userguide/logging.html)
- [付録D Gradle コマンドラインGradle Command Line](http://gradle.monochromeroad.com/docs/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)

Answer (score 2):

プロジェクト直下のgradlewを実行すればビルドが実行可能です。
開発環境はWindows/Linuxどちらでも変わりません。

オプションを確認したい場合、

`# gradlew -help`

上記コマンドでオプションを確認可能です。

リリースビルドか、デバッグビルドかは以下の様に指定します。

１．デバッグビルド

`# gradlew assembleDebug`

２．リリースビルド

`# gradlew assembleRelease`

３．デバッグ／リリース両方

`# gradlew assemble`